# JavaFx: Processing Events for a Pie Chart

Tags: java, charts, highcharts, javafx-8

I have created a javafx pie chart and want to do something when the user clicks on a slice of the pie. I am following this tutorial:[Tuto](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/pie-chart.htm#CIHFDADD)

I use the same code but the problem my label is not showing on node of data.[image]

This is my code

```
    GraphOne.setData(pieChartData);
    for (final PieChart.Data data : GraphOne.getData()) {
        data.getNode().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {

                caption.setTranslateX(e.getSceneX());
                caption.setTranslateY(e.getSceneY());
                caption.setText(String.valueOf(data.getPieValue()) + "%");

            }
        });
    }
```

The code of Tutoriel:

```
final Label caption = new Label("");
caption.setTextFill(Color.DARKORANGE);
caption.setStyle("-fx-font: 24 arial;");

for (final PieChart.Data data : chart.getData()) {
    data.getNode().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                caption.setTranslateX(e.getSceneX());
                caption.setTranslateY(e.getSceneY());
                caption.setText(String.valueOf(data.getPieValue()) + "%");
             }
        });
}
```

[image]

**My question is How i can bind position of label with mouseEvent ?**

Answer (score 1):

I think the tutorial has dropped some code because we can't show `JavaFX controls` such as `Label` without adding it to a `javafx.​scene.Parent`  and  the code didn't add it so how it can be shown!!

Here's the same code where we added the `Label` to a `Tooltip` and show the `Tooltip` itself which contains the `Label`

```
final Label caption = new Label("");
caption.setTextFill(Color.DARKORANGE);
caption.setStyle("-fx-font: 24 arial;");
Tooltip container = new Tooltip();
container.setGraphic(caption);

for (final PieChart.Data data : chart.getData())
{
 data.getNode().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED,
         new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
            {
              @Override
              public void handle(MouseEvent e)
              {
                if (container.isShowing())
                {
                    container.hide();
                }
                caption.setText(String.valueOf(data.getPieValue()) + "%");
                container.show(stage, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
            }
        });
    }
```

**It's preferred to use Java 8 Lambda Expressions and Streams**
so the code will be

```
final Label caption = new Label("");
    caption.setTextFill(Color.DARKORANGE);
    caption.setStyle("-fx-font: 24 arial;");
    Tooltip container = new Tooltip();
    container.setGraphic(caption);

    chart.getData().forEach((data) ->
    {
        data.getNode().
                addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e ->
                {
                    if (container.isShowing())
                    {
                        container.hide();
                    }
                    caption.setText(String.valueOf(data.getPieValue()) + "%");
                    container.show(stage, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                });
    });
```

Hope this is useful